# zcat skip streaming first line while reading from a compressed file

Tags: bash, gunzip, zcat

I am using the zcat command and streaming a .tar.gz file through a piping operation. I want to skip the first line while zcat reads the file. How is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pipe the output to tail, passing `-n +2` to start at the second line:

```
zcat file | tail -n +2
```

Comment: Thanks ! Is there a way to do it directly without using tail intermediate ?

Comment: I don't think there is, zcat's man page has no mention of anything like that. You'll need something else to do that, and tail is a really good candidate for this use case.